# Optimize int incrementing

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have the following code to let a UILabel have incremented animation. ( go from 0 to value x )

```
var i:Int = 0;
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    animateIncrementUILabel(counterLabelOne, labelValue: 30)
    animateIncrementUILabel(counterLabelTwo, labelValue: 22)
    animateIncrementUILabel(counterLabelThree, labelValue: 19)
}

func animateIncrementUILabel(label: UILabel, labelValue: Int)
{
    let arr: Array = [label, labelValue]

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("update:"), userInfo: arr, repeats: true)
}

func update(timer: NSTimer!)
{
    let arr = timer.userInfo as! NSArray
    let lbl = arr[0] as! UILabel
    let amount = arr[1] as! Int

    if(i > amount)
    {
        timer.invalidate()

    } else {
        lbl.text = String(i)
        i++
    }
}
```

Somehow they values are not correct on every label the first one is correct but the second and third one miss 1 or 2 add ups. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
class LabelIncrementVC:UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label2:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label3:UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        animateIncrementUILabel(label, maxValue: 30)
        animateIncrementUILabel(label2, maxValue: 22)
        animateIncrementUILabel(label3, maxValue: 19)
    }

    func animateIncrementUILabel(label: UILabel, maxValue: Int) {
        let arr:NSMutableArray = [label, maxValue, 0]

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: arr, repeats: true)
    }

    func update(timer: NSTimer!) {
        let arr = timer.userInfo as! NSMutableArray
        let lbl = arr[0] as! UILabel
        let max = arr[1] as! Int
        var val = arr[2] as! Int

        val++
        lbl.text = String(val)
        if val >= max {
            timer.invalidate()
        }

        arr[2] = val
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different counter variable for each `UILabel`.

if those labels are dynamic use an NSMutableArray of counters.

**Alternatively, get the value on the label to know why is next:**

```
func animateIncrementUILabel(label: UILabel, labelValue: Int)
{
    let arr: Array = [label, labelValue]

    label.text = String(0)

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("update:"), userInfo: arr, repeats: true)
}

func update(timer: NSTimer!)
{
    let arr = timer.userInfo as! NSArray
    let lbl = arr[0] as! UILabel
    let amount = arr[1] as! Int
    let counter = lbl.text.intValue
    if(counter > amount)
    {
        timer.invalidate()

    } else {
        lbl.text = String(counter+1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use the NSMutableArray of counters?

Comment: Thats not working man. It just shows the value 3 ( probably because I have 3 UILabels...

Comment: I updated multiple times. are you sure you used the last one. please, recheck. it should work.

Comment: Yes I used the last one. the lil.text.intValue doesn't work by the way had to change to let counter: Int = Int(lbl.text!)!

Comment: I do objective c. not swift excuse me for that. I will try it my self.